# Django AJAX call: Referencing Table in JS

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.4, django-1.7

Is there a way I can reference a list containing data from my database (item_list = inventory.objects.order_by('name')) in my jquery AJAX call?

This is my code:

/models.py:

```
class phonebook(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

/views.py:

```
def phonebook_home(request):
    global phonebook
    phonebook = phonebook.objects.order_by('name')

def get_next_3_contacts(request):
    returnedContacts = phonebook[contactIndex:contactIndex+3]
    return HttpResponse(phonebook)
```

/main.js:

```
var = ajax_call {
    type: 'GET'
    url: DEFINED_URL 
    data: {
        index: contactIndex
    },
    dataType: 'html'
    success: function (returned, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored) {
        var contactIndex = 0
        function phonebook_list(name, phone_number) {
            "<li>" + name + " : " + phone_number + "</li>"
        }
        for(var index=0; index < 3; index++) {
            var name = phonebook[index].name
            var phone_number = phonebook[index].phone_number
            $("ul").append(phonebook_list(name, phone_number))
        }
        contactIndex += 3
     }
```

The phonebook[index].name / .phone_number returns "undefined" on my page. I want to keep my js file separate from my template file as it will be easier for me to debug, but unfortunately, this problem has stumped me. I also inputted an alert to test out if any data was being returned from the data base, which only returns a string containing the names of the contacts with no spacing in between contact names. Ex:   "JaredSarahJohn".

All help and any bit of advice is appreciated!

Comment: did you see the data format that the ajax callback is receiving ? You would have to json encode the data (json.dumps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things need to be cleaned up in order for this solution to work:

Your idea that `global phonebook` will be available from within `get_next_3_contacts()` is incorrect. When you make the AJAX call that will ultimately invoke `get_next_3_contacts()` the variable `phonebook`  is no longer available. It went out of scope when the call to `phonebook_home()` completed.

What's the solution? Change `phonebook_home()` to accept an offset and count parameters. Have it hit the database and return the requested quantities. This is called *pagination* and is something you should get familiar with!

```
def phonebook_home(request, offset, count):
    phonebook = phonebook.objects.all()[offset:offset+count]
```

But how do we get those results down to your AJAX handler? You can't just "return" a list of objects to the `HTTPResponse()` function - it's looking for text to render, not Model objects.

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
def phonebook_home(request, offset, count):
    status = "OK"
    return_data = ""

    try:
        phonebook = phonebook.objects.all()[offset:offset+count]
        return_data = json.dumps(phonebook)
    exception:
        status = "UH OH"

    return JsonResponse({'data': return_data, 'status': status)
```

Comment: Thanks, rob. Your advice makes sense. I refactored my code using the example you provided, yet it seems to be returning nothing. Was I supposed to change something in the js as well? I also eddited the name = and the var phonenumber = portions and inputted dummy code to see if that would do anything as well, but it didn't. Nothing is appended to the ul.

Comment: Use your browser's debugging feature and try doing some debug logging to the console to see what's being returned by the server. console.log(returned); should yield some answers for you!